# What is by default capacity of list?How many elements can a list store?

Tags: java, collections

**My first question is** I want to select 100000 elements from database,can list store that many elements? 
**My second question is** I want to fetch all the elements from database in minimum time?Is list is the best way to store elements or is there any other way which can improve performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to select 100000 elements from database,can list store that many elements?

Yes.  There is an upper limit on the size of an `ArrayList` (2^31) ... but you are a long way off that.  And some other `List` implementations don't have that limit.

> I want to fetch all the elements from database in minimum time?  Is list is the best way to store elements or is there any other way which can improve performance?

Most of the CPU time will be spent performing the query and reading from the resultset rather than appending to the list.

The performance of the collection will depend on the element type (object or primitive), and on whether or not you know how many elements there will be.  A bare array will give you the best performance if you know the element count beforehand, and an `ArrayList` if you don't know<sup>1</sup>.  For the case of a primitive types, consider using the "trove" list type instead to avoid the overhead of using primitive type wrappers.

<sup>1 - That is ... unless you are prepared to implement an ArrayList-like expansion algorithm for your array based collection.</sup>

Comment: "And other List implementations don't have that limit." - so what does the `size()` method returns on such a hypothesized list with more than 2^31 elements? Or what do you pass to the `get` method to get the (2^31 + 1)-th element?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt - 1)  If the list contains > 2^31 elements, `size()` returns `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.  See the javadoc.  2) You can't index past 2^31 - 1, but you can iterate.  For the list implementation classes provided by Java SE, that is kind of moot.  Calling `get` or `set` with an index that large on a linked list is insanely expensive.  For a custom list class that supported huge lists, you would overload the get and set methods.

Comment: @Stephen so what is the limit of other list implementations how do we calculate it and How does arraylist give better performance than LIST?

Comment: @TruePS - 1) LinkedList is unlimited.  The other Java SE list implementations (AFAIK) are all array based, and therefore limited.  For 3rd-party list implementations ... look at the source code / documentation.  2) You look at the source code and/or the javadoc.  3) That question doesn't make sense.  `List` is an interface.

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes, list can store 100000+   elements.The maximum capacity of an List  is limited only by the amount of memory the JVM has available.

2) For performance issues, it depends on the type of data to be stored. Normaly HashMaps are used for databases.

Comment: I don't have key value pair concepts so can't use hashmap I was looking for an alternative of List for faster performance if there is any?

Comment: Then use List if you dont have keys

Comment: !AJ. So other than Hasmaps there is no way to improve performance or to reduce time?

Comment: @TruePS Both have have different features. If you are selecting only one column from the data base then use `List`. If you are selecting multiple columns which are depended and one is having unique id then `HashMap` is better.

Answer (score 1):

i normally use list over your quota, and lists is a good way. If you use string is really great but what about raw type?

Comment: I am storing everthing in list then converting them according to datatype.

Comment: Generically objects? I think is ok

Comment: No i am not using generic objects I am just storing everything in list then converting them to diiferent datatypes I need.

Comment: It's OK but map also is OK.. I don't know but i think it's the same.

Answer (score 1):

you can store Integer.MAX_VALUE elements in List I suspect since the value of index can not accept more than this.

Comment: I want approximate limit.

Comment: Integer takes 4 Bytes in java.If an unsigned integer is used for storing index then it can store from 0 - 2^32 - 1 .

Answer (score 1):

The maximum size of a `List` is limited by the maximum value of a Java integer, because integers are used to index the list and to return the size of the list in the method `int size();`. The maximum value of an `int` in Java is `Integer.MAX_VALUE` which is 2147483647.

A particular implementation of `List` could have a lower limit, but for `java.util.ArrayList`, that is the limit.

Of course you could run out of memory long before that, that really depends on the memory of your computer and whether you are using a 64-bit version of the JVM or the 32-bit version.

**For your second question:** the time it takes to transfer data from the database is almost always far higher than the time taken to store the data in the memory of the computer, so if you only worry about the time it takes to store the data in the list, then you should not worry.
If you however are thinking about the time it takes to retrieve the data, then it really depends on how you are retrieving the data from the collection (using a particular key for example).

In many cases, an implementation of `java.util.Map` such as `java.util.HashMap` will have better performance when you are retrieving data by a particular key.

Comment: If i am using simple list not arrayList then limit is also same.Right?

Comment: @TruePS `ArrayList` implements `List` so limit is same for both.

Comment: @AJ The above user said arrayList gives better performance than list.Do you know how?

Comment: In java, List is an interface and interfaces and you always need an implementation for the interface. There are two common implementations that most people use: ArrayList and LinkedList. They both are only limited by Integer.MAX_VALUE and by the amount of available memory.

Comment: @Erwin I am using hibernate and storing values in list as List li=query.list() so if I use Arraylist there will there be any difference.

Comment: Hibernate's Lists have no extra restrictions on the size. (Technically, if you are using an indexed collection mapping for the list, and you make the database column too small, you could be creating your own restriction - make sure that the database columns used for the list index is large enough in that case)

Answer (score 1):

- List can store more that 100000 elements. The list capacity is only bound by the JVM memory capacity or Integer.MAX_VALUE whichever is less.
- However, If you use know the number of elements that will be retrieved, then, using a simple array gives far better performance.

Comment: firstly if I am usin 32-bit JVM or 64- bit JVM what is the limit in both cases and how arrayList gives better performance than list?

Comment: Have a look at http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2013/04/what-is-maximum-heap-size-for-32-bit-64-JVM-Java-memory.html for jvm heap size capacities. As for the second point, I did not say arraylist, if you know the size, use a simple array[]

Answer (score 1):

> can list store that many elements?

Many implementations of `java.util.List` do not restrict the number of elements, i.e. the number of elements is only limited by available heap memory.

The most commonly used List implementation, `ArrayList`, is limited to about 2 billion elements (Integer.MAX_VALUE), because that is the maximum length of a Java array.

Other `List` implementations, such as the Lists returned by `Arrays.asList()`, `Collections.emptyList()`, or `Collections.singletonList()`, have a fixed size, and can not be added to.

> Is list is the best way to store elements or is there any other way which can improve performance?

If all you need is to store the elements for later iteration, an ArrayList is probably the best choice, but compared to the cost of communicating with a database, the overhead of *any* collection implementation will be insignificant, as the database will generally have to perform disk I/O, which is far slower than writing the data to main memory, and writing the actual data (the objects in the list) will take longer than writing the Collection itself.

Comment: that so if I am not using arraylist I am using only list to store values that also means I can store 2 billion elements in a list.Is that right? and secondly can you explain this line in a little detail "the overhead of any collection implementation will be insignificant"

Comment: The first depends on which list implementation is used, i.e. which class was specified in the class instance creation expression that created the list object, such as `new ArrayList<Whatever>()` or `new LinkedList<Whatever>`.